# matrix containing number of occurrence corresponding to each element in the matrix

Tags: r, matlab, matrix

I have matrix, suppose

```
A = [1 2 3 1 1 1 2 3]
```

I want to find number of times the number appeared in the matrix. The output matrix for this i/p would be

```
B = [1 1 1 2 3 4 2 2]
```

i.e. 1 appeared 4 times in the array, hence last value corresponding to 1 is 4.

`unique` and `sum unique` do not help because it gives total number of times the element occured, but I want another matrix which increases the count every time it occurs.

Comment: You want a total or a running total?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
B = ave(A,A,FUN=function(x) 1:length(x))
```

Comment: `ave(A, A, FUN=seq_along)` is what I normally use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty simply with the following code. This will assume that the A matrix is one dimensional, but this is not too big of an assumption to make.

```
A=[1 2 3 1 1 1 2 3];
vals = unique(A);
B = zeros(size(A));
for i = 1:numel(vals)
   idxs = find(diff([0,cumsum(A == vals(i))]));
   B(idxs) = 1:numel(idxs);
end
```

This solution is for MATLAB, not R. I do not know which one you want. If you want an R answer, I would recommend one of the other people's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in MATLAB:

```
B = sum(triu(bsxfun(@eq, A, A.')));
```

Answer (score 0):

For Matlab:

```
B = sum(tril(repmat(A,length(A),1)).' + tril(repmat(NaN,length(A),length(A)),-1) == repmat(A,length(A),1))
```

If `A` is guaranteed not to contain zeros, this can be simplified to:

```
B = sum(tril(repmat(A,length(A),1)).' == repmat(A,length(A),1));
```

Comment: This method fails if `A` contains zero.